# How to monitor an RSS with Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, g-suite, zabbix

I'd like to setup Zabbix monitoring for the [Google Apps Status Dashboard](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en), and I was thinking that monitoring the [RSS Feed](http://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en) with Zabbix's WEB monitoring would be the best way to approach it. However, I can't seem to find any information on how to monitor an RSS with Zabbix. Does anyone have any experience in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more specific information regarding what exactly you want to react to.

For starters, though, you can perform basic parsing of an RSS feed using standard tools in the CLI, piping the results to `zabbix_send` easily:

```
$ curl -g http://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en -s | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item" -v "title" -n -v "dc:date" -n
Postini Services
2014-02-26T16:56:00Z
Postini Services
2014-02-26T15:40:00Z
Postini Services
2014-02-26T14:06:00Z
```

Comment: I'm mainly looking to get an alert whenever any of the Google Apps we use have any sort of issues. You're solution is great, I'll definitely be using that. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of piping the output to zabbix_send, I placed the script with your command in the "externalscripts" folder in the Zabbix installation directory (`/usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscrips/` for me). I then added an item for the host with type "external check", and an item name matching the script filename. This executes the script and returns the values into Zabbix. Thanks again!