# Monitoring AWS RSS feed with zabbix

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, zabbix

I ran into this post [How to monitor an RSS with Zabbix](https://serverfault.com/questions/578487/how-to-monitor-an-rss-with-zabbix)

and want to the same for all 4 AWS regions https://status.aws.amazon.com/

but no idea how to start

Comment: Why you can't use AWS native solution: AWS CloudWatch events (+AWS Personal Health Dashboard)? If you really need it in the Zabbix, then create CloudWatch rule, which will use Lambda to push data to Zabbix.

Comment: @JanGaraj Doesn't it seem a little counter-intuitive to monitor the status of something using itself?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution on GitHub,tested it and it works:https://github.com/tech-sketch/zabbix_aws_template/wiki/AWS-Service-Health-Dashboard-monitoring-Template